# how to switch position of category banner and breadcrumbs in magento

Tags: php, magento, categories

[How it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX5M3.png)

[How i would like to have it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh9wf.png)

Hi to all. I am working on a Magento installation with the porto theme. I created a category description and it works but this category description keeps goin on top of the breadcrumbs and looks horrible. I am trying to switch the position of the two elements but i'm not able to do it. Do hou have some suggestions for me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

2 way it possible 1st is you can change in file and 2nd using jQuery.
Using jQuery you can simple copy that part and put whatever you want.

If you know Magento well then change in file this is ideal way.

Comment: i don't know magento well but surely better than jquery. The problem is i am searching for the files where i have to switch the code, can you give me a hint on where to find them or are all themes build in different ways?

Comment: If you want to find file path then turn on profiler you will get everything. you just go to `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Profiler > Yes` but make you sure that you are in particular store.